# Rationalizing the Use of Non-linear Regression Model

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am studying the relationship between anxiety and graduation exam results when I did the data visualization the relationship seemed to be non-linear
[The relationship between anxiety and exam score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2epkE.png)

this non linear relationship become more obvious as I controlled for the GPA in the past years

[The relationship between anxiety and graduation exam results while controlling for GPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qINBz.png)

using a line that follows a quadratic relationship

[Graphing the relationship using quadratic formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvelg.png)

so I decided to use the model

NMUE score = GAD-7 + GPA + (GAD-7)^2 + (GAD-7)*(GPA) + ((GAD-7)^2)*(GPA)

My question here how I can rationalize the use of my model I did in my paper? should I tell them that I concluded this from graphing of my data?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about programming.  I suggest https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ as being a better alternative, or maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no, it is about regression modeling @StephenC

Comment: And regression modelling is mathematics or computational science, not programming.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding, okay I will repost it there